# Meteor - React: Add custom fields to loginButtons

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm using account-ui to implement a drop-down login in meteor. The problem is that I can't extend user sign-up and add First and Last-name fields. Meteor account ui only proposed email/username and password. Here is my code:

```
export default class AccountsWrapper extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
    }
    componentWillUnount(){
        Blaze.remove(this.view);
    }
    render(){
        return <span ref="container" />;
    }
}
```

[image: What i have]

[image: What i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `accounts-ui` package does not provide a way to accomplish this. You could try using one of the `useraccounts` packages as they have the ability to customize the form fields.

With React though, I find it relatively easy to create custom login/signup forms using the `uniforms` and `simpl-schema` npm packages.

You could of course if you wanted to, just keep using `accounts-ui` and change the sign up flow to be a stepped process where they enter additional details after the initial account creation.